# XSLT: change node type

Tags: xslt

I have an application which stores its data as xml-serialized classes. Due to a refactoring being performed internal collections were changed to be type safe. I.e. before they were of type object[] even though each collection stored only a particular type of objects and now they are MyType[].

For example a collection called Parameters was serialized:

```
<Parameters>
   <anyType xsi:type="Parameter">
   ...
   </anyType>
</Parameters>
```

Become:

```
<Parameters>
   <Parameter>
   ...
   </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

I need to convert old xml files to a new format. So I need to convert all nodes matching
`<anyType xsi:type="Parameter">` to `<Parameter>` and so for 10 or 20 other collections and types.

Can anyone advise what kind of a transformation this would be?

Comment: Using `<xsl:template match="anyType[@xsi:type = 'Parameter']"><Parameter><xsl:apply-templates/></Parameter></xsl:template>` seems the obvious "translation" of your verbal description "I need to convert all nodes matching `<anyType xsi:type="Parameter">` to `<Parameter>`" into XSLT code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more verbose version which retrieves the name of the new element from the xsi:type and also copies other attributes if present. Now you have three approaches and you should be able to compile your custom version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 
  
  <xsl:template match="anyType[@xsi:type]">
    <xsl:element name="{@xsi:type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[not(name()='xsi:type')]" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This would be a bit too much for me as it changes all objects in xml to particular types while I only need to change elements of some collections. But I may adapt the criteria to Parameters\anyType[@xsi:type] + other collection types. This is a nice point to start. I mark it as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a single template rule for this:

```
<xsl:template match="anyType">
  <Parameter><xsl:apply-templates/></Parameter>
</xsl:template>
```

together with the identity template rule which copies everything else unchanged.